Python Watchdog Observer Triggering Function Twice on Directory Changes
I am using the watchdog module in python to monitor a directory for any changes (like adding or deleting files). I've set up an observer and and event handler to trigger a function whenever a change occurs. However I notice that my function gets triggered twice whenever I add or delete the file. I suspect it might be related to how the event handling is set up, but I can't pinpoint the exact cause. I am working on Flask API and I have added this watchdog code on the same file as flask (app.py). I am creating observer just before creating the Flask endpoint.
Here's the sample code:
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(f"Event: {event.event_type} - {event.src_path}")
        time.sleep(2)
        texts = load_data()
        try:
            function_to_trigger(texts)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

path = <directory_path>
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler,path,recursive=True)
observer.start()
print("observer started running...")

How can I ensure that my function is triggered only once per event? Is there something i am missing in the setup of the watchdog observer or event handler?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I have also tried to use single event like on_delete() and on_added(), but issue remains the same.
